# Boto3: How can I set Security Group Ids to default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python, boto3

I am trying to set security group ids while creating an EC2 instance. If I have a specific security group Id list, I can do this:

```
boto3.resource(resource, region_name=self.region)
ec2 = self.resource

instances = ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId=image_id,
        MinCount=minCount,
        MaxCount=maxCount,
        InstanceType=instance_type,
        SubnetId=subnet_id,
        KeyName=key_pair,                
        SecurityGroupIds=security_groups)
```

If I don't have the security group ids I'd like to use a default security group ids that get associated to `launch-wizard-#` security group if I don't pass `SecurityGroupIds` argument in `ec2.create_instances`. Is there a way to pass something to `SecurityGroupIds` argument that tells  boto3 to use default security group Id? More specifically:

```
instances = ec2.create_instances(
            ImageId=image_id,
            MinCount=minCount,
            MaxCount=maxCount,
            InstanceType=instance_type,
            SubnetId=subnet_id,
            KeyName=key_pair,                
            SecurityGroupIds= <"What do I pass here so that boto3 takes in defaults?">)
```

So that I get the same behavior as below (using the previous code snippet):

```
instances = ec2.create_instances(
                 ImageId=image_id,
                 MinCount=minCount,
                 MaxCount=maxCount,
                 InstanceType=instance_type,
                 SubnetId=subnet_id,
                 KeyName=key_pair)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `launch-wizard-#` SGs are created by the console launch wizard, they are not "default" in any way.

On the other hand each VPC has a `default` SG that can be assigned to instances, however it's not very useful. E.g. it doesn't permit inbound access from outside.

I recommend against relying on any implicit defaults. Better create a new SG in your boto3 script before creating the instance and then assign it to the instance.

See [**Working with Security Groups in boto3**](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/ec2-example-security-group.html) for details.